# Why can I not display the map neither with PyCharm nor with Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, conda

I am using PyCharm and anaconda. But none of them can find *ipyleaflet* module. Using the *Conda list* command, I however can see that the module ipyleaflet is installed. I get this error while running the code:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipyleaflet'
```

This is a code line I am running to test the ipyleafet module

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, Marker

start_loc = (52.204793, 360.121558)
m = Map(center=start_loc, zoom=16, scroll_wheel_zoom=True)
display(m)
```

Does someone have an idea of how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your environment? Where are you running the `conda list` command? What interpreter are you using in PyCharm? Are you sure it's the same one as the one you installed `ipyleaflet` in?

Comment: I am running the conda list command in the **terminal**. I use macOS Catalina.**python 3.6 (myEnv)** is the interpreter I use. I can see ipyleaflet there as well. It was not there before I installed it.

Comment: Try running it from a python3 jupyter notebook by typing `jupyter notebook` in the terminal.

Comment: Did you install it using `pip` or `conda`? Using what command? Are you using Jupyter Lab or Jupyter Notebook? Have you read [this potentially related issue](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/issues/29)?

Comment: I installed it using the conda command : <conda install -c conda-forge ipyleaflet>. I use Jupiter Notebook. I will read the link you provided.

Comment: You're not running the program with the correct Python installation, is my guess.